# Finding the Min/Max of subsets of data without the use of an Array/VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two columns of data, say something like Fruit and Weight. I need to parse this data to find the minimum value within each individual subset - the smallest weight of all apples listed, for example.

Unfortunately, using array formulae isn't really an option given the size of my data set and how crappy our work computers are and we're barred from using VBA for reasons unknown.

DMIN seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, but the way its parameters must be structured make it unhelpful here.

edit: data set built daily and will change. data set is currently 1000+ total rows with 700+ unique values.

I cannot provide a sample of my data because it's sensitive client information and whatnot, but this image (originally from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2683-excel-find-max-min-value-based-on-criteria.html) describes what I'm trying to do. I just need to avoid the array formula and do it on a much larger scale.

[image]

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad can't share anything directly from my data (client info and stuff) but I've edited in an image that's representative of what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the answer, make a new column, AppleWeight, and inside:

`=if(FruitCol="Apple",WeightCol,"")`

then =Min() on that column.

or make a [pivot table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPtso.png)

Comment: unfortunately my data set's much too large to be able to use a helper column for each unique value, and the values aren't necessarily known beforehand.

Comment: @Tock Are you saying that you need the minimum number for all 700+ unique  fruits (or products), not just one selected one as in the picture you posted? If that's the case, then the pivot table solution should work for you.

Comment: Thats a good point, you could remove duplicates first. Large data sets are supposed to be ok with power pivot using the data model.  The pivot table will calc your min, no problem. If your data set is too big, you have binary solution, you need to find another app, e.g. python, or you need to cut your data into pieces.